Topological measure theory on spaces that are not completely regular
In the usual discourse regarding approaches to measure theory, it is often pointed out that the restriction of topological measure theory to locally compact Hausdorff spaces is insufficient. However, much of this theory has some degree of generalization to completely regular spaces. Are there any areas where measures on spaces that are not completely regular actually come up? If so, what are some good examples?
